# Cross-Origin Request Blocked Spring REST service + AJAX

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax, spring

Unable to call spring REST service

My spring service

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/MAS/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> authenticate(@RequestBody Subject subject) {
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
    result.put("result_detail", "Invalid Password");
    result.put("result", "failure");
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // also added header to allow cross domain request for any domain
    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>>(result, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

My AJAX code

```
$.ajax(
{
  crossDomain: true,
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  async: false,
  url: "http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/rest/MAS/authenticate",
  headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"},
  data:{},
  dataType: "json", //also tried "jsonp"
  success: function(data, status, jqXHR)
  {
    alert('success');
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, status)
  {
    alert('error');
  }
});
```

I am getting following error :(

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/rest/MAS/authenticate. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

i have also tried `dataType: "jsonp"`. its append my body object into URL which make different URL and cannot hit my service URL then and got 404 error.

My browser: firefox 36.0.4

How i can get rid from this error, any help?

Comment: you are using which server ?

Comment: @ Halayem Anis : i am using webSphere but also tried on tomcat. get same error on both

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My AJAX call and service were OK. After searching a lot on internet i have found that its server side problem not client side.

on server side with Spring we have to implement filter which will allow CORS requests.

filter will look like this.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CORSFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            LOG.trace("Sending Header....");
            // CORS "pre-flight" request
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            // response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

and in web.xml apply this filter on your service requests like this

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.test.common.controller.CORSFilter</filter-class> <!-- your package name and filter class -->
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

This may help someone else who went through this problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

By default the only method allowed is a `GET`, and you don't allow the `POST` on your server side:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This header only enables CORS, but you need to add this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET
```

[More detailed how-to about the `HTTP access control (CORS)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) on Mozilla project

So your code should be something like this:

```
responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET"); // also added header to allow POST, GET method to be available
responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // also added header to allow cross domain request for any domain
```

**Update**:

I have re-read the article, and found out some details:

> A simple cross-site request is one that:
>
> - Only uses GET, HEAD or POST. **If POST is used to send data to the
>     server, the `Content-Type` of the data sent to the server with the HTTP
>     POST request is one of application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
>     multipart/form-data, or text/plain.**
> - Does not set custom headers with
>     the HTTP Request (such as X-Modified, etc.)

As you can read in bold, you must set other `Content-Type` for your data (currently it is `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`) or use the preflight technique described later:

> - It uses methods other than GET, HEAD or POST.  Also, if POST is used
>     to send request data with a Content-Type other than
>     application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain,
>     e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the server using
>     application/xml or text/xml, then the request is preflighted.
> - **It sets custom headers in the request** (e.g. the request uses a header such as
>     X-PINGOTHER)

So I suggest you either change the contentType or try to work with this header into your request:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-HEADER_NAME_OF_YOUR_CHOOSE
```

and this headers into your response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-HEADER_NAME_OF_YOUR_CHOOSE
```

And after that you can try to call your method.

Comment: added "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET" in service but still getting same error :(

Comment: Updated the answer, try to read the original article and try out their solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, i have tried your other suggestion but unable to get rid form this error :(

Answer (score 2):

Following is the solution for cross platform spring boot web service call.

Application URL: http://localhost:8080

Webservice URL: http://localhost:9090

In your spring controller use following annotation

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
@RequestMapping(value = "/uri", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public SomeObject someMethod(){
// your logic will come here
}
```